# How to simulate a void data type?

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I know about void pointers, that they can point to an object of any type. So if I want to have a linked list with elements that store data of an unknown type, I could use `void*`:

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    void* data;
};
```

But what if I don't want to use a pointer but I still don't know what type of data `Node` will carry? Is there a way to have `data` with no particular type? I tried `auto` but it's not working because it needs to have an initializer to be deduced right away.

Comment: Did you already consider a template based solution??

Comment: Which aspects of `void` do you want?  Just the ability to point at a type of your choosing (perhaps determined at run time) or the ability to prevent others from dereferencing the type?  A template would be one way to get the first.

Comment: Do you want the same data type in each element of the linked list or different ones? Use templates in the first case ans unions in the second (in which case you have to store the information about the data type separately)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use templates. They are a form of generic typing in C++. I won't write an entire tutorial here but here's the general form:

```
template<typename T>
return_type function_name(parameters) {

}
```

In the case of creating templated objects, you can do the following:

```
template<typename T>
struct struct_name {
    T member_name;
};
```

Here, "template" and "typename" are actual keywords in C++. "T" can be any name you want.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Edit: I want to stress the following which is probably the most important non-trivial thing about templates in C++ which is discussed in the link I provided:

> Because templates are compiled when required, this forces a
>   restriction for multi-file projects: **the implementation (definition)
>   of a template class or function must be in the same file as its
>   declaration.** That means that we cannot separate the interface in a
>   separate header file, and that we must include both interface and
>   implementation in any file that uses the templates.

Comment: cplusplus.com is riddled with errors… do you have another source? Also it's worth noting that different parameterizations of the same template are different types. So this provides a way of generating different `Node` classes, not having any data in a given Node.

Comment: To be honest I posted the first link I found that was related. If you happen to have a good link I will edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with educational literature. Here's one my friend wrote, accurate and up to date, and approachable albeit not as extensive: http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/Beginning/templates.php

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, C++ is fundamentally incapable of having an object whose type wasn't determined at compile time. The generic idea you seem to be describing is called *type erasure,* a process for transparently generating all the compile-time types you need for any queries that might actually happen. A common library is [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html). Now I see Boost has also a newer [type erasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) library, for broader and more advanced usage.

Type erasure still requires you to know something about the types the object may potentially hold. You get operations like "give me an `int` from this if possible."

Templates are not the same thing. A template `Node<T>` would provide a different type of Node for each T, so the entire data structure formed from the nodes would be dedicated to storing a particular type, not a mix. This is how the [C++ standard library](http://cppreference.com) works, and you should generally use that instead of writing your own data structures.

Answer (score 1):

As **c++ is statically typed, So all types must be resolved in compile time**. And void variable cann't be decleared, because compiler wouldn't know how much memory to allocate.

**There may be a illusion of runtime type discovery, but actually that is not possible in c++.** A template based solution may work fine for some perpouse. But truely I can't hold arbitrary type in a variable.

Comment: He's doing a pointer to a void, not a void variable. That's different.

Comment: Yes. and I'm telling that. There may be a illusion of runtime type discovery, but actually that is not possible. @PawełStawarz

Answer (score 1):

Using `void*` to represent "an unknown value of any (pointer) type" is common in C. In C++ however, there is a better solution -- namely using templates.

The general form would be:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    T data;
};
```

and you'd then declare a `Node<int>` (or whatever type you wanted to hold in your list).

Templates are extraordinarily powerful but can get quite complicated. I'd recommend reading about their use in your favourite C++ textbook.